# File System Sink with parquet format doesn't work

Tags: apache-flink

I have following code snippet that is to demonstrate writing data to file in streaming mode. But when the application starts to run, I checked the output directory, I observe that no data is written and the `_SUCCESS` doesn't exist

Each partition(eg: `p_day=2021-04-30\p_hour=18\p_min=52`)contains about 58 files(each one is empty file, looks one file is created every second),the name is like `.part-01c10c8a-5ffa-4ffc-91d0-57ed68d85c93-0-0.inprogress.1cc628a9-0f88-46ca-9d14-7f10db332184`. If I change  `'format' = 'parquet',` with  `'format' = 'csv',` and leave the other code unchanged, then the application works and successfully writes the data as csv and `_SUCCESS` appears in each partition.

The application code:

```
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.example.sources.{InfiniteEventSource, MyEvent}

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
object T007_ParquetFormatFileSystemSink {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.enableCheckpointing(20*1000)
    env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///d:/flink-checkpoints"))
    val ds: DataStream[MyEvent] = env.addSource(new InfiniteEventSource(emitInterval = 5 * 1000))
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    tenv.createTemporaryView("sourceTable", ds)

    ds.print()

    //Change  'format' = 'parquet', to  'format' = 'csv', then the application works
    val ddl =
      s"""
      create table sinkTable(
      id string,
      p_day STRING,
      p_hour STRING,
      p_min STRING

      ) partitioned by(p_day, p_hour, p_min) with (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'D:/csv-${System.currentTimeMillis()}',
        'format' = 'parquet',
        'sink.rolling-policy.check-interval' = '5 s',
        'sink.rolling-policy.rollover-interval' = '20 s',
        'sink.partition-commit.trigger'='process-time',
         'sink.partition-commit.policy.kind'='success-file',
        'sink.partition-commit.delay' = '0 s'
      )
      """.stripMargin(' ')
    tenv.executeSql(ddl)

    tenv.executeSql(
      """
     insert into sinkTable
      select id, date_format(occurrenceTime,'yyyy-MM-dd'), date_format(occurrenceTime, 'HH'), date_format(occurrenceTime, 'mm')  from sourceTable

     """.stripMargin(' '))

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

The `InfiniteEventSource` code

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.{RichSourceFunction, SourceFunction}
case class MyEvent(id: String, occurrenceTime: Timestamp)

class InfiniteEventSource(emitInterval: Long) extends RichSourceFunction[MyEvent] {
  var id: Long = 1
  val running = new AtomicBoolean(true)

  override def run(sc: SourceFunction.SourceContext[MyEvent]): Unit = {
    while (running.get()) {
      sc.collect(MyEvent(id.toString, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime)))
      if (emitInterval > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(emitInterval)
      }
      id += 1
    }

  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    running.set(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem sink requires that checkpointing is enabled, and pending files are only finalized during checkpoints.

This is especially noticeable with Parquet, since this is a bulk format that has a checkpoint-based rolling policy.

It could also be that you are running into [this issue](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#general):

> Given that Flink sinks and UDFs in general do not differentiate between normal job termination (e.g. finite input stream) and termination due to failure, upon normal termination of a job, the last in-progress files will not be transitioned to the “finished” state.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson， I have already enabled the checkpoint. And during the running, I noticed the checkpoint should work. I have found the `chk-XXX/_metadata`  file in the checkpoint data directory,and the number is increasing.